# zakhar_asli only has one question and it does not make sense

Tags: discussion, new-users

[RAM Disk related questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217853/ram-disk-related-questions) is closed as a duplicate of a closed question. I object on general principles as having dupes of closed is frustrating for everyone involved, but both questions are asked by the same user, both appear to be the same question, neither makes any sense (definitely muddled thinking leading to an unclear question). I saw this come up in the reopen que, and voted to leave closed, but was wondering if there is anything we can do to help this fellow (or at least get him to stop slurping soup with a spoon).

Comment: +1 for the spoon analogy. I wasn't sure how to help him further. If people feel there's a nugget of a good Q in what he's asking I encourage you to edit it to try and flesh it out. I generally will rewrite Q's and A'ers like this 1 to help the situation out, and 2 to help show new users what our expectations are for Q&A. In this case, there's several directions to go w/ this and wasn't sure how to help this user either.

Comment: As to the dup of closed, we've done this several times in the past where the OP has asked a Q, and then had it closed, then reposts another (same Q) which is then closed. This feels like how that part of the system should work (at least in this set of circumstances). It's annoying but again, w/o a more fleshed out Q it's hard to provide assistance w/in the space of the SE Q&A format. For that level of assistance, for a kind soul willing to help a user out, the private chats via comments is our best option, IMO. But I'm open to suggestions.